# Triggering a view's controller function from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I have created a directive which allows one to add an entry to a database. All of those entries are shown in a table below. Therefore, if a new entry is made, the view should update, showing all entries, including the new one.

I added a function **to the views controller** which updates the view.

I am using a shared service to trigger the viewControllers function from within my directive

```
$scope.$watch('branch.trigger',function(){
    _updateView();
});
```

When the entry is made, the services `trigger` property will be toggled.

Is this the way to go or does another method exist to achieve that, which i am unware of?

Comment: need more detail. What does `_updateView();` do and how are new entries added to data array? A demo would help

Answer (score 0):

For what I can understand from your question, I think you may want to have a CRUD Service shared between these two controllers, say you call this service "MyDataCrudService" and it has a member "data" which is an array of the data you are displaying.

If you bind your table to show the data on that service, all you need to do, is every time you do an operation on MyDataCrudService is to return the newly updated data from the server, and then you assign it back to the data member of the CRUDService, that will automatically make your table update and all the elements in your web application that are binded to that data will automatically be updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this plunker should be able to help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jlVyer?p=preview